# set chars to uppercase between parenthesis

Tags: vim, regex

let's assume in vim I have following lines:

> all what (strong) people have to do is pushing (heavy) weights
>
> over (and over) again in order to gain muscles

and I need to convert words inside parenthesis to uppercase, what is the most convenient way to do so? How do I tell vim it needs to select everything to the first (!) closing parenthesis? So far I came up with

```
:%s/\s(.*)\s/\U&/g
```

unfortunately this will uppercase everything between 'strong' and 'heavy' which is not what I want. Any chance to tell vim it should select the chars to the next closing bracket only? (sorry for the silly example, couldn't think of something more sophisticated... or at least vim related... huh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in `vim`:

```
:%s/\s([^)]*)\s/\U&/g
```

Using `.*` is 'greedy': it will match all characters, including the first `)` on the first line, and go on until the last `)`, thus capitalizing everything in between.

Using `[^)]*` tells the regex engine to look for any characters that are **not** a `)` within `()`, and capitalize them. Basically, it forces the match to be 'lazy' rather than 'greedy'.

See the sections "Laziness vs Greediness" and "An Alternative to Laziness" in the [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Comment: @sevanto accepted your answer for giving me the hint to the regex tutorial! Think I have plenty of food for thought with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This substitution does what you want:

```
:%s/(.\{-})/\U&/g
```

Like savanto said, `*` is greedy: it matches 0 or more, *as much as possible,* of the preceding atom. Here I just use the opposite of `*`: `{-}` to match 0 or more, *as few as possible,* of the preceding atom.

Comment: Heh, I tried that but it didn't work -- I forgot to escape the `{` =)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you only need to uppercase the first parenthesis :

Put your cursor inside parenthesis - anywhere - and press `gUi(`

```
gU " change to uppercase and wait for a motion
i( " it s for "inside parenthesis"
```

Comment: yes, good one. Actually my next approach would have been record a macro: `:norm! gg0/(\<cr>gg0` and after that something like `qqngUi)q3@q`. Since the original file I was referring onto is a more complex latex file I was curious to solve this issue by regex. Thank you though, a macro may even be the simpler solution in this case! EDIT: would like to upvote your answer but I'm still under 15 su points -.-

Comment: EDIT2: ww.. w... would you ^^ please!